# CUDA coordinates hit

Tags: arrays, cuda

I am trying to implement a rather simple averaging during transformation of an image. I already successfully implemented the transformation, but now I have to process this resulting image by summing up all pixels of all 5x5 pixels rectangles. My Idea was to increment a counter for each such 5x5 block whenever a pixel in this block is set. However, these block-counters are by far not incremented often enough. So for debugging I checked how often any pixel of such a block is hit at all:

```
    int x = (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int y = (blockIdx.y*blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

    if((x<5)&&(y<5)) 
{
    resultArray [0]++; 
}
```

The kernel is called like this:

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(8, 8); 
dim3 grid(targetAreaRect_px._uiWidth / threadsPerBlock.x, targetAreaRect_px._uiHeight / threadsPerBlock.y);
CudaTransformAndAverageImage << < grid, threadsPerBlock >> > (pcPreRasteredImage_dyn, resultArray );
```

I would expect resultArray [0] to contain 25 after kernel execution, but it only contains 1. Is this due to some optimization by the CUDA compiler?

Comment: The kernel is called like this:
dim3 threadsPerBlock(8, 8);
dim3 grid(targetAreaRect_px._uiWidth / threadsPerBlock.x, targetAreaRect_px._uiHeight / threadsPerBlock.y);

CudaTransformAndAverageImage << < grid, threadsPerBlock >> > (pcPreRasteredImage_dyn, resultArray );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if((x<5)&&(y<5)) 
{
    resultArray [0]++; 
}
```

is a read after write hazard.

All of the threads which satisfy `(x<5)&&(y<5)` can potentially attempt simultaneous reads and writes from `resultArray[0]`. The CUDA execution model does not guarantee anything about the order of simultaneous memory transactions.

You could make this work by using atomic memory transactions, for example:

```
if((x<5)&&(y<5)) {
    atomicAdd(&resultArray[0], 1);
}
```

This will serialize the memory transactions and make the calculation correct. It will also have a big negative effect on performance.

You might want to investigate having each block calculate a local sum using a reduction type calculation and then sum the block local sums atomically or on the host, or in a second kernel.

Comment: Thank You so much for Your advice! That really saved the day for a CUDA-newbie! :-)